# How to provide images for iPad 2x Version of app in iOS 5

Tags: image, ipad, ios5, icons

All,

I have an app, that at least in this release will be just for iPhone. I do however want the 2x view on the iPad to look decent, too.
I know that the @2x.png naming convention is used to give the iPad larger images for tab bar icons but what about other image assets that I am using on the iPhone? Do I just create images that are twice as large as the iPhone images and apply the same naming convention of [filename]@2x.png?

Thank you!

Comment: the answer for your question in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611061/how-to-support-both-ipad-and-iphone-retina-graphics-in-universal-apps)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

if you load them with:

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"filename"] // note the lack of .png and @2x
```

It will automagically grab the correct image.